# Custom object inspection in Chrome development console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I wonder — does Chrome development tools support something like Ruby `inspect` or Objective C `description` methods to print some meaningful string instead of just showing the object constructor name when you explore the objects in the console.

[image: clarifying screenshot]
So in that case — instead of showing "Crossing, Crossing, Crossing, ..." it would show some custom string for each object (generated by a method of that object).

ps. I know that there is a `console.table` method which can produce some nice output, but it still would be nice to have a more universal object formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the feature you are looking for is **custom formatters**

Basically you must enable the feature in Chrome and make that during the start process of your script, you write your formatters into the magic global var `window.devtoolsFormatters`

The official doc:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1FTascZXT9cxfetuPRT2eXPQKXui4nWFivUnS_335T3U/preview